Access to the private network from the cloud9
I have the server which has 172.31.50.95 and not have public IP in the private subnet.
Now I try to access this from the cloud9 which is in public subnet.
$wget 172.31.50.95
--2024-09-09 15:02:23--  http://172.31.50.95/
Connecting to 172.31.50.95:80... 

It can not be reached.
Now, I am confused a bit.
This IP(172.31.50.95) is only valid in the same subnet? , so I can not reach?
Or is it the problem of security group?
However my EC2 has the security group which accepts all 80 0.0.0.0/0 access and http server is running.
These are my routing table for public and private.
Public

Private

check route tables and NACLs between your private subnet and public subnet

I edited the article and put the route table.

All subnets in a VPC can communicate with each other. Have you installed a web server on the 172.31.50.95 instance? Is the Cloud9 instance running in the same VPC?

@John Rotenstein, I see, that's the basic thought, All subnets in a VPC can communicate with each other.. Cloud9 and web server are in the same VPC, and instance has web server , but I want to confirm more, permit Echo Reply from 0.0.0.0 in EC2 security group and try to ping from cloud9 but in vain.
